# Can emit from cleanup method in storm?

Tags: java, image-processing, apache-storm

I have a bolt that gets data from DB and does some process on data and then sends it to another bolt as a double array.

The new bolts needs data of all those arrays to find a value. and I only need this value once. And it should be done after the process I just mentioned.

How can I make sure that this bolt only emits data when its process is done?

And how can I use the output of it?

And here is my topology:

```
//Topology definition
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

builder.setSpout    ("sample-split",new SampleSplit(), 1);
builder.setBolt     ("tuple-split", new TupleSplit(), 1)
            .shuffleGrouping("sample-split");
builder.setBolt     ("read-images", new ReadImage (), 10)
            .shuffleGrouping("tuple-split");
builder.setBolt     ("filter-image", new FilterImage (), 10)
        .shuffleGrouping("read-images");
builder.setBolt     ("wavelet-transformation", new WaveletTransformation (), 5)
        .shuffleGrouping("filter-image");
//builder.setBolt     ("PNMSTD", new PNMSTD (), 5 ).
//    shuffleGrouping ("wavelet-transformation");
```

I want to implement this code on Storm :

```
public static double[][] PNMSTD(String MS,double []MP, double []MN,String TrainingSetFile,String WvdecFileDir,
            String TestAnnotationLevelFromorOnly,int TestAnnotationID,int TestAnnotationLevel)
    {
    BufferedReader inFile;
    int Psamples=0;
    int Nsamples=0;
    int N=0;
    try {
        inFile=new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(TrainingSetFile));
        String StrSqls=inFile.readLine();
        String TSet[]=StrSqls.split(", ");
        String DataFile=WvdecFileDir+"/e"+TSet[1]+"_1.dat";
        double C[]=FileIO.Xread(DataFile);
        N=C.length;
        inFile.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    double []MSP=new double[N];
    double []MSN=new double[N];
    double [][] MeanStd=new double[2][N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        MSP[i]=0;
        MSN[i]=0;
    }
    try {
        inFile=new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(TrainingSetFile));
        String StrSqls;
        while ((StrSqls=inFile.readLine() )!= null){
            //String StrSqls=inFile.readLine();
            //System.out.println(StrSqls);
            String TSet[]=StrSqls.split(", ");
            String DataFile=WvdecFileDir+"/e"+TSet[1]+"_1.dat";
            double C[]=FileIO.Xread(DataFile);  
            if(TestAnnotationLevelFromorOnly.equals("From"))
            {
                if (Integer.parseInt(TSet[TestAnnotationID+4])>=TestAnnotationLevel)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (MS.equals("Mean")){
                        MSP[i]=MSP[i]+C[i];}
                        else{MSP[i]=MSP[i]+(C[i]-MP[i])*(C[i]-MP[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    Psamples++;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (MS.equals("Mean")){MSN[i]=MSN[i]+C[i];}
                        else{MSN[i]=MSN[i]+(C[i]-MN[i])*(C[i]-MN[i]);}

                    }
                    Nsamples++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Integer.parseInt(TSet[TestAnnotationID+4])==TestAnnotationLevel)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
                    {if (MS.equals("Mean")){MSP[i]=MSP[i]+C[i];}
                    else{MSP[i]=MSP[i]+(C[i]-MP[i])*(C[i]-MP[i]);}
                    }
                    Psamples++;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<C.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (MS.equals("Mean")){MSN[i]=MSN[i]+C[i];}
                        else{MSN[i]=MSN[i]+(C[i]-MN[i])*(C[i]-MN[i]);}
                    }
                    Nsamples++;
                }
            }   
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();       
    }   
    for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
         {
             MeanStd[0][i]=MSP[i]/Psamples;
             MeanStd[1][i]=MSN[i]/Psamples; // Meaningless should be asked!!!
         }      
    return MeanStd;
}
```

For this function to work, I need files to be created. And the previous bolt is processing and creating those files. And for next bolt I need this bolt to finish its process on all the inputs. (So I can use the output in next bolt.)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking... can you give an example? It looks like your bolts are processing images and each bolt needs the complete image? If so, you can't break the image up into tuples... you should send the whole image as the tuple.

Comment: I want one of my bolts do start processing when the previous one is totally finished. But I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Maziar what is the point of using cleanup? You could do your stuff in the bolt and then, once it is done, emit a tuple from it. Or is there something I don't understand?

Comment: @zenbeni Imagine we have two bolts A and B. I want A to send tuple to B. But B only emits while it got everything from A. B is doing a kind of finding average of data in DB. So B doesn't get all the data at once.

Comment: @Maziar do you plan calculating a sliding window? Bolt B is calculating an average per period: nb of items / minute on the last 10 minutes for instance. Is it what you want to do?

Comment: @zenbeni there is a DB that has the files name. I read the DB (in sample-split) then I open and read the image file and create a 2D array of that and send it (filter-image). the wavelet-transformation creates a 1D array. Now I need all arrays at the same time ( imagine this one creates a variable named v. The next bolt needs v to do it's process. So I have to make sure previous bolt have got all the data and then it will emit results to the last bolt.

Comment: So you'll need a variable to group tuples together (filename?) and then you'll probably need some count and length variables in order to know when you've received all the tuples and reassemble them.

Comment: @KitMenke there isn't any better way to do this ? Like somehow stoping a bolt before the previous one get finished ?

Comment: Your topology is running 24/7 and so are your spouts/bolts. There is no "stopping" your bolt because it will be constantly processing tuples that are emitted from the previous bolt.